# What should I do about crack in concrete subfloor? A foundation contractor has already stabilized the foundation

Tags: concrete, crack, self-leveling-concrete

About two years ago I noticed some cracks in the drywall, so we had a foundation contractor come out and stabilize our foundation. They removed all the trees close to the house, added gutters and sump pump, but they did not remove the flooring and fix the cracks. I removed the carpet in my living room, and there is a crack that goes from wall to wall about 14ft long, and every 4ft a crack branches off on each side. The area around the crack has lifted about 3/4 in, and the area close to the wall has sunk about 3/4 in. I grinder down the area of the crack so that I could fill it and then pour self leveling compound. I was going to use ARDEX Artifix to patch the crack and ARDEX k15 to level. Is that the right approach, or what do you recommend? I know someone who does concrete and he said I could cut out the floor and pour a new floor,  it I don’t know if that is really necessary, what do you think?[image]

Comment: You cant patch the cracks if portions have risen or sunk.  They will probably keep doing it

Answer (score 0):

Advice I got from my contractor:

If you are sure the building is not settling, this is mostly a cosmetic issue, though if you are in an area with significant radon rising from the soil the cracks may admit more than would otherwise come on.

You can patch it adequately with hydraulic cement, preferably following instructions to first shape the crack's edges and roughen the surface so the cement can get a better grab on the existing concrete.

Note that eye protection and dust mask should be worn when working with these materials, either hammering on them or mixing them.

Comment: What about Ardex artifix, would that be a good solution?